# 2x2 system of first order ode's

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$t\cdot x'(t)=\left(\begin{matrix}1 &1\\ 0&2\end{matrix}\right)x(t)+\left(\begin{matrix}2t\\ t\end{matrix}\right)$ with $x(1)=\left(\begin{matrix}1\\1\end{matrix}\right)$

How do is start solving this problem? I have no clue (because of the **t** on the left)...

Comment: If this is an ode, where is the derivative?

Comment: forgot the ', changed it

Comment: Do you know about matrix diagonalization? Divide the equation by $t$, substitute $x=My$ where $M^{-1}\left(\begin{matrix}1 &1\\ 0&2\end{matrix}\right)M$ is diagonal because $M$ contains the eigenvectors of $\left(\begin{matrix}1 &1\\ 0&2\end{matrix}\right)$ and then you have two decoupled equations you can solve relatively easily for $y_1, y_2$ and then substitute $y$ into $x=My$ to get $x$.

Comment: So $M=\left(\begin{matrix}1 & 0.701\\ 0 & 0.701\end{matrix}\right)$. If i then divide by t and substitute $x=My$ i get $y'(t)=\left(\begin{matrix}1 & 1.402\\ 0 & 1.402\end{matrix}\right)\cdot \frac{1}{t}\cdot y(t)+\left(\begin{matrix}2\\ 1\end{matrix}\right)$. Then i can solve $y_{2}$ first and then solve $y_{1}$. Is that correct Graham? Or am i doing the substitution wrong?

Comment: Ok i see what i forget in my last comment. It should be  $y'(t)=\left(\begin{matrix}1 & 0\\ 0 & 2\end{matrix}\right)\cdot \frac{1}{t}\cdot y(t)+\left(\begin{matrix}2\\ 1\end{matrix}\right)$. Then i have two decoupled equations.

Comment: Almost, the decoupled matrix is correct but you have not acted $M^{-1}$ on the additional column vector

Comment: and btw, $M= \left[ \begin {array}{cc} 1&1\\ 0&1\end {array}
 \right],M^{-1}=\left[ \begin {array}{cc} 1&-1\\ 0&1\end {array}
 \right] 
$ works just as well because the eigenvectors are only defined up to a normalization.

Comment: so $y'(t)=\left(\begin{matrix}1 & 0\\ 0 & 2\end{matrix}\right)\cdot\frac{1}{t}\cdot y(t)+\left(\begin{matrix}1\\ 1.414\end{matrix}\right)$

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the initial condition doesn't actually satisfy the equation, therefore you can't solve this particular equation....

Evaluating $x(1) =
  \begin{pmatrix}
   1\\
   1
  \end{pmatrix}$

We get

$(1) *  \begin{pmatrix}
   1\\
   1
  \end{pmatrix} =   \begin{pmatrix}
   1 && 1\\
   0 && 2 
  \end{pmatrix} *  \begin{pmatrix}
   1\\
   1
  \end{pmatrix} +   \begin{pmatrix}
   2\\
   1
  \end{pmatrix}$

Evaluating this gives

$\begin{pmatrix}
   1\\
   1
  \end{pmatrix} =   \begin{pmatrix}
   2\\
   2 
  \end{pmatrix}  +   \begin{pmatrix}
   2\\
   1
  \end{pmatrix}$

And we see

$\begin{pmatrix}
   -1\\
   0
  \end{pmatrix} =   \begin{pmatrix}
   2\\
   2 
  \end{pmatrix}$

This isn't true

Comment: @sahil M The question was incorrectly stated earlier, my answer was correct for that question. Watch who you say is incorrect =\

Answer (score 1):

Given:

$$t\cdot x'(t)=\left(\begin{matrix}1 &1\\ 0&2\end{matrix}\right)x(t)+\left(\begin{matrix}2t\\ t\end{matrix}\right), x(1)=\left(\begin{matrix}1\\1\end{matrix}\right)$$

We can divide by $t$ and rewrite this as:

$$x'(t)=\dfrac{1}{t}\left[\left(\begin{matrix}1 &1\\ 0&2\end{matrix}\right)x(t)+\left(\begin{matrix}2t\\ t\end{matrix}\right)\right], x(1)=\left(\begin{matrix}1\\1\end{matrix}\right)$$

Note that the second equation is decoupled from the first (and a good thing, given we have a time varying system).

The second equation can be solved by itself and the substituted back into the first, and then the first can be solved by itself.

So, we have:

$$y'(t) = \dfrac{2}{t} y(t) + 1, y(1) = 1$$

We can use integrating factor to solve for $y(t)$ and this yields:

$$y(t) =  t (2 t-1)$$

Substituting back into the first equation yields:

$$x'(t) = \dfrac{1}{t} \left(x(t) + y(t) + 2t\right) = \dfrac{1}{t}x(t) +2t + 1, x(1)=1$$

Again, we can make use of integrating factor, which yields:

$$x(t) =t (2 t+ \ln t-1)$$

Comment: You've been on a very helpful roll! +1

Comment: Soooooo close you are to $\geq 20\mathbb k$!

Answer (score 0):

The voted answer is incorrect, as x'(t=1) has been evaluated as [1 1], where it cannot be evaluated from the initial condition, we only know x(t=1).

What you can do, is rewrite the equation

t⋅x′(t)=A.x(t)+t.b (constants A and b)

Divide the equation by t,

x′(t)=(1/t).A.x(t)+b

Integrating both sides,

x(t) = A.log(x(t)) + b.t + c

You will have to solve the question hereon, using the initial conditions.

[1 1] = [0 0] + [2 1] + c

=> c = [-1 0]

x(t) = A.log(x(t)) + b.t + c

I can help you till here, if this helps. You still need to resolve because this you have two terms in x(t).

Comment: there was an edit to the question

Comment: i was incorrect, forgot the ' in the equation

Comment: Oops didn't follow the timeline, my bad @JohnDodson!